# Trying to integrate NetBeans and Gluon SceneBuilder

Tags: java, user-interface, gradle, netbeans, gluon

Could you please give me some advice, cause all those YouTube videos seem to be created not in my universe

1. Javafx tab is missing in my NetBeans 8.1;
2. I downloaded Gluon Plugin and it asked for Gradle Support;
3. I downloaded Gradle Support plugin and it required Groovy Support
4. Groovy Support is a jar file which I added as a libraby but the sys keeps telling me this:
   **

> ***Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.modules.groovy.support to be installed. The plugin org.netbeans.modules.groovy.support is
>   requested in version 1.40.1.  The following plugin is affected:
>         Gradle Support  Some plugins require capability cnb.org.netbeans.gradle.project No plugin providing the capability
>   cnb.org.netbeans.gradle.project could be found.  The following plugin
>   is affected:       Gluon Plugin  Some plugins require capability
>   cnb.org.netbeans.modules.groovy.kit No plugin providing the capability
>   cnb.org.netbeans.modules.groovy.kit could be found.  The following
>   plugin is affected:       Gradle Support  Some plugins not installed
>   to avoid potential installation problems.***
>   Sorry If it is painful to read but it's even more painful to fix. I am pretty sure there should exist a normal way to do it...All the story is written in Ubuntu btW

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be thinking of it the wrong way. 
If you are trying to work with Scene Builder to create FXML files, I think I can help. 
When You create your FXML Files with scene builder, You can add it to the Netbeans package as below:
[FMXL File in Netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5a0j.png)

Then you create a new class that extends the Application class as below: 
[Controller Class for FXML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T2Kr.png)